# How do I get my unordered bulleted list to line up straight?

Tags: html, css

I have attached my HTML and CSS below, along with a screenshot of the webpage. The bulleted list is not formatting correctly. I want them to form a straight line in the middle with the bullets right beside the words and evenly lined up in the center. Also, my header and footer, both red, look so much wider than the rest of the webpage; how would I fix this?

```css
/*

Landon Byrd
Fall 2021

    Plain Red       #f60d41
    Rich Red        #f6130d
    Orioles Orange  #f64d0d
    Sunset Orange   #f6870d
    Golden Yellow   #f6c10d

*/


/* Global settings */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Papyrus
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f6130d;
  text-decoration: underline
}

.wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Nav Section */

.nav {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 25%
}


/* Main section */

.banner {
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f6c10d;
  text-align: center;
}

.bulletPoints {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #f6870d;
  color: #f60d41;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 25px 50px 75px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpeg");
}

.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Footer section */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%
}

.footer::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}


/* Copyright section */

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Home</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Shop</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Events</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Contact Us</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</nav>
<main class="wrapper">

  <div class="banner">
    <h1><span class="name">Augie's Custom T-shirts</span></h1>
    <h2>Custom T-shirts for you or your party.</h2>

    <div class="bulletPoints">

      <ul>
        <li>Birthday parties</li>
        <li>Vacation groups</li>
        <li>Bachelorette Parties</li>
        <li>Family reunions</li>
        <li>Work team rewards</li>
        <li>Business promotions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>


  </div>
  <p id="Catch">
    Do you have an event coming up, and want everyone to get in the spirit? T-shirts can bring a group together, make everyone feel connected, and let everyone know what you're celebrating.
  </p>

  <p>T-shirts can also be a great gift to someone that acknowledges their special interest or hobby.</p>

  <p>Choose from one of our unique designs, or let us put your own design on a shirt for you.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/gorilla.jpg" alt="Gorilla" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Pink" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/skull.jpg" alt="Skull" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p><strong>How it works:</strong></p>

  <p>Browse our selection of unique designs, select the size and colors of the shirts you would like, and place your order. We will ship your shirts within three business days for in-stock shirts, or five days for custom size and colors.</p>

  <figure>
    <img src="images/t-shirt-colors.jpeg" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
    <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors!</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <p>Have a design of your own? Can't find the right sentiment? Call or email us to discuss the possibilities or get some ideas for your event.</p>

  <p>Please note there will be a one time $15 charge for any custom graphics design.</p>




  <h2><em>Contact us today!</em></h2>


</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Augie's Custom T-shirts</p>
    <p>(478) 555-1212</p>
    <p>augieB@augiesTees.com</p>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Check out are Social Media for updates!</p>
    <p>Facebook:</p>
    <p>Instagram:</p>
    <p>Twitter:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Locations:</p>
    <br/>
    <p>100 Tanger Dr, Locust Grove, GA</p>
    <p>2954 Watson Blvd Suite 100, Warner Robins, GA</p>
  </div>
</footer>

<div class="copyright">
  <h3> @copyright: Landon Byrd</h3>
  <p>Fall 2021, All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>

<p>
  <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
    <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!" />
  </a>
</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
.bulletPoints ul {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

This way the list width would same as the longest line, and it will be aligned to the center as you already gave the property to the container. Just need to align the list to the left (as to overwrite the center alignment inherited from parent.)

```css
/*

Landon Byrd
Fall 2021

    Plain Red       #f60d41
    Rich Red        #f6130d
    Orioles Orange  #f64d0d
    Sunset Orange   #f6870d
    Golden Yellow   #f6c10d

*/


/* Global settings */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Papyrus
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f6130d;
  text-decoration: underline
}

.wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Nav Section */

.nav {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 25%
}


/* Main section */

.banner {
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f6c10d;
  text-align: center;
}

.bulletPoints {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #f6870d;
  color: #f60d41;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 25px 50px 75px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpeg");
}

.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Footer section */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%
}

.footer::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}


/* Copyright section */

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f6130d;
  color: #f6c10d;
}

.bulletPoints ul {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Home</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Shop</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Events</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Contact Us</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</nav>
<main class="wrapper">

  <div class="banner">
    <h1><span class="name">Augie's Custom T-shirts</span></h1>
    <h2>Custom T-shirts for you or your party.</h2>

    <div class="bulletPoints">

      <ul>
        <li>Birthday parties</li>
        <li>Vacation groups</li>
        <li>Bachelorette Parties</li>
        <li>Family reunions</li>
        <li>Work team rewards</li>
        <li>Business promotions</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>


  </div>
  <p id="Catch">
    Do you have an event coming up, and want everyone to get in the spirit? T-shirts can bring a group together, make everyone feel connected, and let everyone know what you're celebrating.
  </p>

  <p>T-shirts can also be a great gift to someone that acknowledges their special interest or hobby.</p>

  <p>Choose from one of our unique designs, or let us put your own design on a shirt for you.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/gorilla.jpg" alt="Gorilla" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Pink" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="images/skull.jpg" alt="Skull" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p><strong>How it works:</strong></p>

  <p>Browse our selection of unique designs, select the size and colors of the shirts you would like, and place your order. We will ship your shirts within three business days for in-stock shirts, or five days for custom size and colors.</p>

  <figure>
    <img src="images/t-shirt-colors.jpeg" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
    <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors!</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <p>Have a design of your own? Can't find the right sentiment? Call or email us to discuss the possibilities or get some ideas for your event.</p>

  <p>Please note there will be a one time $15 charge for any custom graphics design.</p>




  <h2><em>Contact us today!</em></h2>


</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Augie's Custom T-shirts</p>
    <p>(478) 555-1212</p>
    <p>augieB@augiesTees.com</p>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Check out are Social Media for updates!</p>
    <p>Facebook:</p>
    <p>Instagram:</p>
    <p>Twitter:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Locations:</p>
    <br/>
    <p>100 Tanger Dr, Locust Grove, GA</p>
    <p>2954 Watson Blvd Suite 100, Warner Robins, GA</p>
  </div>
</footer>

<div class="copyright">
  <h3> @copyright: Landon Byrd</h3>
  <p>Fall 2021, All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>

<p>
  <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
    <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Nice solution, and better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

That's how lists work in a centered element, I'm afraid. However, there is a solution!

The problem is that you have a `div` that spans the whole width of the page, within which you've asked for the text to be centered. And your browser has done exactly what you asked for. However, the rule for where the bullets are positioned is that they go to the left of the *entire* text line. So, when the line is centered, they are off to the left, as you see. (Basically, the `text-align` applies to the text but not to the bullets, which are technically outside the text itself.)

The solution is to remove the `text-align: center` and instead to position your `bulletPoints` div so that this container is centered while the list inside remains left-aligned. You could, for example, do something like this, although you'll need to fiddle with the width to make it suit the layout you want:

```css
.bulletPoints {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The result will be a list that has the text and bullets properly aligned, but that is centered in the view. This is achieved by the `margin` property: by setting the left and right margins to `auto`, you are telling the browser so make them the same, and the only way to do this on an element that's narrower than the available space is to center it.

However, this way of doing things does mean you need to be careful about the responsiveness of your design, and ensure that things display properly on very wide and very narrow windows. For example, on a phone, you won't want to set the width to 50%. So `media-query` will be your friend!

(Your problem with the red blocks is that you've written the code in a way that produces a result you don't like. To solve it, we need a clearer idea of what you actually want - probably best in a separate question because it's a completely different thing to the list. In general, though, you could wrap the page in a container `div` that you can set to a max width, which will stop these becoming very wide (or just wrap the content of the header and footer in a container, so the red is full width but the text is constrained). But we'll need a clearer idea of what you want to give a better solution, as I say!)

Comment: I will make a new question for that, I changed the code for the list but it still is not aligning. The bullets came in a bit but not all the way beside the text and the text did not align in a straight line.  .bulletPoints{width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;}